# VIrtualBox: How to update the VBox.log location for a VM

Tags: virtualbox

After moving a VM into an external disk and updating the VM's disk image files, starting up the VM will show this warning

Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
Checking if hardware virtualization is enabled failed: open /Users/hanxue/.docker/machine/machines/default/default/Logs/VBox.log: no such file or directory

The `VBoxManage modifyvm` command does not seem to have an option to specify the log file

```
modifyvm                  <uuid|vmname>
                            [--name <name>]
                            [--groups <group>, ...]
                            [--description <desc>]
                            [--ostype <ostype>]
                            [--iconfile <filename>]
                            [--memory <memorysize in MB>]
                            [--pagefusion on|off]
                            [--vram <vramsize in MB>]
                            [--acpi on|off]
                            [--pciattach 03:04.0]
                            [--pciattach 03:04.0@02:01.0]
                            [--pcidetach 03:04.0]
                            [--ioapic on|off]
                            [--hpet on|off]
                            [--triplefaultreset on|off]
                            [--apic on|off]
                            [--x2apic on|off]
                            [--paravirtprovider none|default|legacy|minimal|
                                                hyperv|kvm]
                            [--paravirtdebug <key=value> [,<key=value> ...]]
                            [--hwvirtex on|off]
                            [--nestedpaging on|off]
                            [--largepages on|off]
                            [--vtxvpid on|off]
                            [--vtxux on|off]
                            [--pae on|off]
                            [--longmode on|off]
                            [--ibpb-on-vm-exit on|off]
                            [--ibpb-on-vm-entry on|off]
                            [--spec-ctrl on|off]
                            [--l1d-flush-on-sched on|off]
                            [--l1d-flush-on-vm-entry on|off]
                            [--cpu-profile "host|Intel 80[86|286|386]"]
                            [--cpuid-portability-level <0..3>
                            [--cpuid-set <leaf[:subleaf]> <eax> <ebx> <ecx> <edx>]
                            [--cpuid-remove <leaf[:subleaf]>]
                            [--cpuidremoveall]
                            [--hardwareuuid <uuid>]
                            [--cpus <number>]
                            [--cpuhotplug on|off]
                            [--plugcpu <id>]
                            [--unplugcpu <id>]
                            [--cpuexecutioncap <1-100>]
                            [--rtcuseutc on|off]
                            [--graphicscontroller none|vboxvga|vmsvga]
                            [--monitorcount <number>]
                            [--accelerate3d on|off]
                            [--accelerate2dvideo on|off]
                            [--firmware bios|efi|efi32|efi64]
                            [--chipset ich9|piix3]
                            [--bioslogofadein on|off]
                            [--bioslogofadeout on|off]
                            [--bioslogodisplaytime <msec>]
                            [--bioslogoimagepath <imagepath>]
                            [--biosbootmenu disabled|menuonly|messageandmenu]
                            [--biosapic disabled|apic|x2apic]
                            [--biossystemtimeoffset <msec>]
                            [--biospxedebug on|off]
                            [--boot<1-4> none|floppy|dvd|disk|net>]
                            [--nic<1-N> none|null|nat|bridged|intnet|hostonly|
                                        generic|natnetwork]
                            [--nictype<1-N> Am79C970A|Am79C973|
                                            82540EM|82543GC|82545EM|
                                            virtio]
                            [--cableconnected<1-N> on|off]
                            [--nictrace<1-N> on|off]
                            [--nictracefile<1-N> <filename>]
                            [--nicproperty<1-N> name=[value]]
                            [--nicspeed<1-N> <kbps>]
                            [--nicbootprio<1-N> <priority>]
                            [--nicpromisc<1-N> deny|allow-vms|allow-all]
                            [--nicbandwidthgroup<1-N> none|<name>]
                            [--bridgeadapter<1-N> none|<devicename>]
                            [--hostonlyadapter<1-N> none|<devicename>]
                            [--intnet<1-N> <network name>]
                            [--nat-network<1-N> <network name>]
                            [--nicgenericdrv<1-N> <driver>
                            [--natnet<1-N> <network>|default]
                            [--natsettings<1-N> [<mtu>],[<socksnd>],
                                                [<sockrcv>],[<tcpsnd>],
                                                [<tcprcv>]]
                            [--natpf<1-N> [<rulename>],tcp|udp,[<hostip>],
                                          <hostport>,[<guestip>],<guestport>]
                            [--natpf<1-N> delete <rulename>]
                            [--nattftpprefix<1-N> <prefix>]
                            [--nattftpfile<1-N> <file>]
                            [--nattftpserver<1-N> <ip>]
                            [--natbindip<1-N> <ip>
                            [--natdnspassdomain<1-N> on|off]
                            [--natdnsproxy<1-N> on|off]
                            [--natdnshostresolver<1-N> on|off]
                            [--nataliasmode<1-N> default|[log],[proxyonly],
                                                         [sameports]]
                            [--macaddress<1-N> auto|<mac>]
                            [--mouse ps2|usb|usbtablet|usbmultitouch]
                            [--keyboard ps2|usb
                            [--uart<1-N> off|<I/O base> <IRQ>]
                            [--uartmode<1-N> disconnected|
                                             server <pipe>|
                                             client <pipe>|
                                             tcpserver <port>|
                                             tcpclient <hostname:port>|
                                             file <file>|
                                             <devicename>]
                            [--guestmemoryballoon <balloonsize in MB>]
                            [--audio none|null|coreaudio]
                            [--audioin on|off]
                            [--audioout on|off]
                            [--audiocontroller ac97|hda|sb16]
                            [--audiocodec stac9700|ad1980|stac9221|sb16]
                            [--clipboard disabled|hosttoguest|guesttohost|
                                         bidirectional]
                            [--draganddrop disabled|hosttoguest]
                            [--vrde on|off]
                            [--vrdeextpack default|<name>
                            [--vrdeproperty <name=[value]>]
                            [--vrdeport <hostport>]
                            [--vrdeaddress <hostip>]
                            [--vrdeauthtype null|external|guest]
                            [--vrdeauthlibrary default|<name>
                            [--vrdemulticon on|off]
                            [--vrdereusecon on|off]
                            [--vrdevideochannel on|off]
                            [--vrdevideochannelquality <percent>]
                            [--usb on|off]
                            [--usbehci on|off]
                            [--usbxhci on|off]
                            [--usbrename <oldname> <newname>]
                            [--snapshotfolder default|<path>]
                            [--teleporter on|off]
                            [--teleporterport <port>]
                            [--teleporteraddress <address|empty>
                            [--teleporterpassword <password>]
                            [--teleporterpasswordfile <file>|stdin]
                            [--tracing-enabled on|off]
                            [--tracing-config <config-string>]
                            [--tracing-allow-vm-access on|off]
                            [--usbcardreader on|off]
                            [--autostart-enabled on|off]
                            [--autostart-delay <seconds>]
                            [--videocap on|off]
                            [--videocapscreens all|<screen ID> [<screen ID> ...]]
                            [--videocapfile <filename>]
                            [--videocapres <width> <height>]
                            [--videocaprate <rate>]
                            [--videocapfps <fps>]
                            [--videocapmaxtime <ms>]
                            [--videocapmaxsize <MB>]
                            [--videocapopts <key=value> [,<key=value> ...]]
                            [--defaultfrontend default|<name>]
```

How can I modify the VBox.log location? The `default.vbox` file does not specify the log location either

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
** If you make changes to this file while any VirtualBox related application
** is running, your changes will be overwritten later, without taking effect.
** Use VBoxManage or the VirtualBox Manager GUI to make changes.
-->
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.15-macosx">
  <Machine uuid="{d2610ffb-f00c-4d36-8a4b-29043b02d2c4}" name="default" OSType="Linux26_64" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2019-01-18T11:27:07Z">
    <MediaRegistry>
      <HardDisks>
        <HardDisk uuid="{fa1480e6-6cf8-410f-a16a-720bbf08ff22}" location="/Volumes/USB/docker/machine/machines/default/disk.vmdk" format="VMDK" type="Normal"/>
      </HardDisks>
      <DVDImages>
        <Image uuid="{e85e5ef4-2c06-401f-9321-d7517a66b321}" location="/Users/hanxue/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso"/>
        <Image uuid="{ab50127f-f7d5-415f-aa05-5981060f0eb4}" location="/Volumes/USB/docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso"/>
      </DVDImages>
    </MediaRegistry>
    <ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition" value="71,198,720,421"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/Users" value="1"/>
    </ExtraData>
    <Hardware>
      <CPU>
        <PAE enabled="true"/>
        <LongMode enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="true"/>
      </CPU>
      <Memory RAMSize="1024"/>
      <HPET enabled="true"/>
      <Paravirt provider="Default"/>
      <Boot>
        <Order position="1" device="DVD"/>
        <Order position="2" device="DVD"/>
        <Order position="3" device="HardDisk"/>
        <Order position="4" device="None"/>
      </Boot>
      <VideoCapture fps="25" options="ac_enabled=false"/>
      <RemoteDisplay enabled="false"/>
      <BIOS>
        <IOAPIC enabled="true"/>
        <Logo fadeIn="false" fadeOut="false" displayTime="0"/>
        <BootMenu mode="Disabled"/>
      </BIOS>
      <Network>
        <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="08002725C9F6" cable="true" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <InternalNetwork name="intnet"/>
            <NATNetwork name="NatNetwork"/>
          </DisabledModes>
          <NAT>
            <DNS use-proxy="true"/>
            <Forwarding name="ssh" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.1" hostport="61378" guestport="22"/>
          </NAT>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="1" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027E950C0" cable="true" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <InternalNetwork name="intnet"/>
            <NATNetwork name="NatNetwork"/>
          </DisabledModes>
          <HostOnlyInterface name="vboxnet6"/>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="2" cable="true" type="Am79C973"/>
        <Adapter slot="3" cable="true" type="Am79C973"/>
        <Adapter slot="4" cable="true" type="Am79C973"/>
        <Adapter slot="5" cable="true" type="Am79C973"/>
        <Adapter slot="6" cable="true" type="Am79C973"/>
        <Adapter slot="7" cable="true" type="Am79C973"/>
      </Network>
      <AudioAdapter driver="CoreAudio" enabled="true" enabledIn="false" enabledOut="false"/>
      <RTC localOrUTC="UTC"/>
      <SharedFolders>
        <SharedFolder name="Users" hostPath="/Users" writable="true" autoMount="true"/>
      </SharedFolders>
      <GuestProperties>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Revision" value="125813" timestamp="1547810530818115000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountDir" value="/" timestamp="1545727366043887000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountPrefix" value="/" timestamp="1545727365986899000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Version" value="5.2.20" timestamp="1547810530817930000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VersionExt" value="5.2.20" timestamp="1547810530818010000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Product" value="Linux" timestamp="1547810530817144000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Release" value="4.14.79-boot2docker" timestamp="1547810530817276000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Version" value="#1 SMP Thu Nov 8 01:56:42 UTC 2018" timestamp="1547810530817380000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID" value="en_US" timestamp="1547810545759333000" flags=""/>
      </GuestProperties>
    </Hardware>
    <StorageControllers>
      <StorageController name="SATA" type="AHCI" PortCount="30" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true" IDE0MasterEmulationPort="0" IDE0SlaveEmulationPort="1" IDE1MasterEmulationPort="2" IDE1SlaveEmulationPort="3">
        <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" hotpluggable="false" port="0" device="0">
          <Image uuid="{ab50127f-f7d5-415f-aa05-5981060f0eb4}"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
        <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" hotpluggable="false" port="1" device="0">
          <Image uuid="{fa1480e6-6cf8-410f-a16a-720bbf08ff22}"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
      </StorageController>
    </StorageControllers>
  </Machine>
</VirtualBox>
```

Comment: Can you try to create link in place where virtual machine expects to put logs and point this link to your external location?

Comment: Soft link will not be helpful - the VirtualBox VM is part of a Docker Machine setup, and I need all the files to be moved to the new location

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is a restructuring of VirtualBox directories, possibly due to upgrading VirtalBox.  I encountered the problem and found a fix today.

I hit the same `Checking if hardware virtualization is enabled failed: open /Users/ZZZZZ/.docker/machine/machines/default/default/Logs/VBox.log` problem. The problem occurred on a docker-machine VM I had used smoothly for weeks.  What went wrong?

I noticed that in the error message, `docker-machine` is looking for the *VirtualBox* log, not something special to Docker.  Now `docker-machine` creates files under `.docker` but they seem to be fairly conventional in terms of VirtualBox, as if `docker-machine` gave `VBoxManage create` just a single folder.

I opened the VirtualBox manager GUI and opened the logs for that VM. There I saw the path for the `VBox.Log` file had a slight detour from what the `docker-machine` was looking for.  My log file was at this location:

`~/.docker/machine/machines/default/Utility/default/Logs/VBox.log`

I fixed it by symlinking, not the `Logs` subdirectory, but the `Utility/default` subdirectory:

`ln -s ~/.docker/machine/machines/default/Utility/default ~/.docker/machine/machines/default/`

Now my `default` docker machine runs as before.

I hope this helps someone!